# Creating a map that acts as a mask for a grid of images underneath

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, canvas, svg

I am not sure whether he is the right place for this question.

**Here is the brief:**

- I am going to create a map of a country.
- The map will act as a mask for a grid of images.  The images can be uploaded by user.
- Those images on the grid can be clicked and a bigger version will get revealed.
- Don't worry about browser / mobile support.

Here is an attachment of what I meant. Try imagining those a black square = an image submitted by user.

[image]

**Solution I can think of:**

- Use CSS clip-path. Combine all the images generated by user to create a collage of grid images. Create the map as an SVG to be use as the mask for the clip-path. The grid images will sit behind the map and get masked by the SVG.
- Can we use Canvas for this? Can we create the map boundary and do some math calculation and the images will sit nicely within the map? Use Canvas libraries like easeljs, kineticjs or p5js.
- Can we use Google map for it and customize it?
- Doing all in SVG with libraries like d3 or snap.

--

I am looking at ideas for how I could approach this.

Comment: A CSS mask or clip-path would be the simplest approach AFAICS.  Plus it has the advantage over Canvas in that the masked images can remain interactive (CSS effects on hover etc).  The trickiest part would be just making sure that the images are positioned in the grid so that they are visible on the map, and not off in the sea areas somewhere.

Comment: You should start by making a version of this image, where you swap black for transparent (save as .gif or .png). So any image under this one (less z-index) gets shown, but you get the sharp shape of the shore.  You can make a css grid; for example classes like class="tile_4_2", and give those position: absolute.  Calculating where an image should be on the map, is easy. Your tiles now, are about 1° (of the 360° world perimeter). Divide (top latitude to bottom latitude of N.Z.) by the numer of tiles you want ...